# mouseposition interaction with THREE.Point

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am learning Three.js and trying to reproduce some cool effects as a training method.

I have a Obj file globe which I want to add some particles interaction to.

my work so far : https://codepen.io/Imsenji/pen/QWOBMWN?editors=0010

What I'm trying to do: https://dala.craftedbygc.com/  ( or similar)

this is my code :

```
// OBJ model

const obj = new OBJLoader();
obj.load("https://res.cloudinary.com/dltqzyazm/raw/upload/v1648118569/2dgame/globe2_gl4laq.obj", function (object) {
  let material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    color: colour,
    size: 0.035,
    // map: cross,
  });
  let mesh = new THREE.Points(object.children[0].geometry, material);

  mesh.scale.multiplyScalar(0.025);
  mesh.rotation.y = 2 * Math.PI * 0.7;
  mesh.position.x = objectsDistance * 0.5;
  mesh.position.y = -objectsDistance * 0.1;
  scene.add(mesh);
});
//----------------------


 * Particles
 */
// Geometry
const particlesCount = 1000;
const positions = new Float32Array(particlesCount * 3);

for (let i = 0; i < particlesCount; i++) {
  positions[i * 3 + 0] = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  positions[i * 3 + 1] =
    objectsDistance * 0.5 -
    Math.random() * objectsDistance * sectionMeshes.length;
  positions[i * 3 + 2] = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
}

const particlesGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
particlesGeometry.setAttribute(
  "position",
  new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3)
);

// Material
const particlesMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  color: "#c0a43c",
  sizeAttenuation: true,
  size: 0.2,
  transparent: true,
  map: cross,
});

// Points
const particles = new THREE.Points(particlesGeometry, particlesMaterial);
scene.add(particles);

//   // Interaction
var uniforms = {
  mouse: {
    value: new THREE.Vector3(),
  },
  radius: {
    value: 3.5,
  },
};

material.onBeforeCompile = (shader) => {
  shader.uniforms.mouse = uniforms.mouse;
  shader.uniforms.radius = uniforms.radius;
  // console.log(shader.vertexShader);
  shader.vertexShader =
    `
    uniform vec3 mouse;
  uniform float radius;
` + shader.vertexShader;
  shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace(
    `#include <begin_vertex>`,
    `#include <begin_vertex>

    vec3 dir = transformed - mouse;

    float dist = length(dir);

    if (dist < radius){
      float ratio = 1. - dist / radius;

      vec3 shift = dir * 2. * (ratio * ratio);

      transformed += shift;
    }

  `
  );
};

var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 0);
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, uniforms.mouse.value);
});
```

it seems like `raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, uniforms.mouse.value);` not working. that's my question.

any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to indicate what problem you are facing.

Comment: take a look at this tutorial, they were using a 2d plane, but if you can understand it, you can try to use it on a 3d model. https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/01/17/interactive-particles-with-three-js/